# RxJava with vertx: can't have multiple subscriptions exception

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying avoid vertx callback hell with RxJava.
But I have "`rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Cannot have multiple subscriptions`". What's wrong here?

```
public class ShouldBeBetterSetter extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        Func1<AsyncMap<String,Long>, Observable<Void>> obtainAndPutValueToMap = stringLongAsyncMap -> {
            Long value = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return stringLongAsyncMap.putObservable("timestamp", value)
                .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                .doOnNext(aVoid -> System.out.println("succesfully putted"));
        };

        Observable<AsyncMap<String,Long>> clusteredMapObservable =
                vertx.sharedData().<String,Long>getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap")
                        .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace);

        vertx.periodicStream(3000).toObservable()
                .flatMap(l-> clusteredMapObservable.flatMap(obtainAndPutValueToMap))
                .forEach(o -> {
                    System.out.println("just printing.");
                });
    }
}
```

Working Verticle (without Rx) can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/IvanZelenskyy/9d50de8980b7bdf1e959e19593f7ce4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vertx.sharedData().getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap") returns observable, which supports single subscriber only - hence exception. One solution worth a try is:

```
Observable<AsyncMap<String,Long>> clusteredMapObservable =
            Observable.defer(
            () -> vertx.sharedData().<String,Long>getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap")
 );
```

That way every time clusteredMapObservable.flatMap() will be called, it will subscribe to new observable returned by Observable.defer().

**EDIT**

In case it's OK to use same AsyncMap, as pointed by @Ivan Zelenskyy, solution can be

```
Observable<AsyncMap<String,Long>> clusteredMapObservable =   
vertx.sharedData().<String,Long>getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap").cache()
```

Comment: Thank you!
Also we can use getClusterWideMapObservable().cache()
Add this to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, seems like there is no much sense in requering AsyncMap, if all you want to do - put a value in it. I ll update my answer for that use case

Comment: @m-ostroverkhov, actually for live-read cached observable works fine too.
It is because AsyncMap is not a 'temporary copy from cluster' but a wrapper over live cluster data. So cached observable here is totally correct, and it is totally okay to retrieve map-object from cluster only once.
And at all in Java all non-primitive variables works 'by-link', and only primitives works 'by-value', so it is always okay to retrieve a mutable objects only once.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that on each periodic emission, the `foreach` is re-subscribing to the `clusteredMapObservable` variable you defined above.

To fix, just move the call to `vertx.sharedData().<String,Long>getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap")` inside your periodic stream `flatmap`.

Something like this:

```
vertx.periodicStream(3000).toObservable()
                .flatMap(l-> vertx.sharedData().<String,Long>getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap")
                        .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                        .flatMap(obtainAndPutValueToMap))
                .forEach(o -> {
                    System.out.println("just printing.");
                });
```

UPDATE

If you don't like labmda in lambda, then don't. Here's an update without

```
vertx.periodicStream(3000).toObservable()
                    .flatMap(l-> {
                        return vertx.sharedData().<String,Long>getClusterWideMapObservable("mymap");
                    })
                    .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                    .flatMap(obtainAndPutValueToMap)
                    .forEach(o -> {
                        System.out.println("just printing.");
                    });
```

PS - Your call to `.flatMap(obtainAndPutValueToMap))` is also lambda in lambda - you've just moved it into a function.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to avoid 'lambda in lambda in lambda'. :)
And also, problem could be solved with defer() and cache()

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy If you don't like lambda in lambda, then don't. I was just copying and pasting your code- see update. Also - I've not looked deep into the code - but think if you want to cache locally a cluster wide map. Might not you lose updates by other nodes?

Comment: it succesfully communicates between verticles anyway. As I found in vertx-core and vertx-hazelcast sources, getClusterWideMap() returns not a copy of Map, but a link to live map, owned by Hazelcast or any other cluster-manager instance.

Comment: Sure - just had a look through the HZ code - I think you're right.